# Calling another function while long polling

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, long-polling

I see that there is a question about this, but I don't know how I would implement it in my case (since I'm not using multiple sessions). Also, I must say that the long-polling itself works, but nothing else does while it runs.

There is javascript file which sets the method, and chat.php file which on this basis either receives messages (starts polling) or sends them. The issue is I can't send the messages if I include the "while" function. Here it is:

from chat.js:

```
chat.fetchMessages = function ()
{
    if(localStorage.getItem("amInQueue") != 1)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../ajax/chat.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { method: 'fetch' },
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 50000,
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data!='')
                {
                    chat.printMessages(data);
                }
                setTimeout(chat.fetchMessages, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
chat.throwMessage = function (message, byuser)
{
    if ($.trim(message).length != 0 && localStorage.getItem("amInQueue") != 1)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../ajax/chat.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { method: 'throw', message: message, byuser:byuser },
            success: function(data)
            {
                chat.entry.val('');
            }
    });
    }
}
```

from chat.php:

```
<?php

require '../core/init.php';
if (isset($_POST['method']) === true && empty($_POST['method']) === false)
{
    $chat       = new Chat();
    $method         = trim($_POST['method']);

    if($method === 'fetch' && $_SESSION['ses_amInQueue']==0)
    {
        $shouldStop=0;
        $messageIDs = $chat->checkForLatestMessage($_SESSION['ses_myChat'], $_SESSION['ses_meInChat']);

        while($messageIDs=='')
        {
            usleep(30000);
            clearstatcache();
            $messageIDs = $chat->checkForLatestMessage($_SESSION['ses_myChat'], $_SESSION['ses_meInChat']);
        }

        if($messageIDs!='')
        {
            $messageString=$chat->getNewMessages($_SESSION['ses_myChat'], $messageIDs);
            $chat->deleteMessages($messageIDs);
            echo $messageString;
        }
    }

    else if($method === 'throw' && isset($_POST['message']) === true)
    {
        $message = trim($_POST['message']);
        $byuser = trim($_POST['byuser']);
        if (empty($message) === false)
        {
            $chat->throwMessage($byuser, $message, $_SESSION['ses_otherInChat'], $_SESSION['ses_myChat']);
        }
    }
```

I can't use "throw" method while the "while" loop is running. I tried checking the method on the end of "while" loop to see if it's "throw" and including it in "while"'s conditions, but that didn't work for some reason.

How do I pull this out? Both work independently, or if I remove "while" loop (but it is then no longer long-polling).

Comment: This may not be an answer to your question but take a look at ratchets beautiful php websocket implementation: http://socketo.me you will be able to receive broadcasts directly by using a non blocking websocket connection. Doing this via http is very ugly and this is not what it is designed for.

Comment: Yes, I intend to look into the websockets but it will delay me for few days. I just want to finish this up, and if it's appealing overall learn how to use websockets.

Comment: There are various threads about your problem. The main reason is your session. Try session write close to make apache be able to open another session from same client. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: I saw something like that suggested but I'm not sure where to put it? When should I start another session in this case? Also will it delete my session data since the long polling function is relying on it (I can change this and make it depend entirely on javascript passed variables though)?

Comment: Call session_write_close before you start your loop. When you need some session vars in your loop copy it to a local variable before. But the main point is: you cannot write to session any more after write close in this request. But the other parallel request is now able to open your session for reading or writing.

Comment: No session data will be deleted. You only close the session for writing in that request. That means you release it for parallel requests cause it is locked if you dont. Reading should be possible after calling i think.

Comment: I will try it, if I can still read them then I don't have to almost rewrite anything (I think it already set all relevant data).

Comment: Thank you so much  steven, I added session_write_close(); before the loop and it works now. If you want to post it as an answer I will confirm it. Also, what is it about my throw function that for whatever reason doesn't start again after 50 seconds? (I can receive messages for 50 seconds, but if I don't receive one within that time, the loop doesn't start again)